# Conservation of mass from material derivative

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mass, conservation-laws, differentiation, navier-stokes

Let the mass be $m=\rho \text{Vol}$, where $\text{Vol}$ is the volume of the domain and the velocity is $u$.

Applying the material derivative, then

$$\frac{Dm}{Dt}=\frac{\partial (\rho \text{Vol})}{\partial t}+ u \cdot \nabla (\rho \text{Vol})=0$$

Since the volume is constant, then it reads

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+ u \cdot \nabla \rho=0$$

However, the conservation of mass (the correct one as far as I know)

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+ \nabla \cdot (\rho u)=0$$

It is not clear What's wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrong is your assumption that Vol *is* constant.  What is constant is the mass within the  volume "Vol".  This  is $M=\rho\, {\rm Vol}$. So as $\rho$ increases ${\rm Vol}$ decreases.

Comment: Yes it is clear from what you write that $\rm Vol$ is a co-moving region containing a fixed mass of the fluid.  I used the word "control" volume. I should not have, as such a volume is usually fixed, and your is not fixed.  I have edited my anwwr.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are perfectly consistent in the particular case that the divergence of the 3-D vector field is zero. Recall, that the mass continuity equation can also be written as:
$$\frac{D\rho}{Dt}=-\rho\cdot\operatorname{div}V.$$